# Correct usage of Postgres JSON conversion functions

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

I am working on a Postgres update transaction.

Let's say I have two tables: `events` and `ticket_books` with event booking types. The ticket_books table has a foreign key pointing to the `events`.

I need to update an event stored in the database, including booking type records from the `ticket_books` table.

To deal with cascading update and delete, I decided to build a transaction, in a "pseudo-code" it looks like:

```
    BEGIN;
      DELETE FROM
        ticket_books
      WHERE
        event_id = ${req.params.id} AND
        id NOT IN (${bookingIds})
      FOR booking IN json_to_recordset('${JSON.stringify(book)}') as book(id int, title varchar(200), price int, ...) LOOP
        IF bookind.id THEN
          UPDATE
            ticket_books
          SET
            title = booking.title, price = booking.price
          WHERE
            event_id = ${req.params.id};
        ELSE
          INSERT INTO
            ticket_books (title, price, qty_available, qty_per_sale)
          VALUES
            (booking.title, booking.price, booking.qty_available, booking.qty_per_sale)
          RETURNING
            id
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
   UPDATE
     event
   SET
    ...
   WHERE
     id = ...
   RETURNING
     id;
   COMMIT;
```

I currently get the error: `syntax error at or near "json_to_recordset"`. I never used `json_to_recordset` or friends before, just saw from the document that from 9.3 and later those are available. Unsure how to get Postgres to understand what I need, though.

I am embedding a JSON array so the final line looks like:

```
FOR booking IN json_to_record('[{"id":13,"description":"Three day access to the festival","title":"Three Day General Admission","price":260,"qty_available":5000,"qty_per_sale":10},{"id":14,"description":"Single day access to the festival","title":"Single Day General Admission","price":"90.90","qty_available":2000,"qty_per_sale":2},{"title":"Free Admission","price":"0.00","qty_available":0,"qty_per_sale":0}]')
```

I believe that my JSON array is valid. Apparently, this is not how I should be passing it to the Postgres. What should I be doing instead? My goal is to iterate over the array entries. If there is an integer value for `booking.id`, I want to update the record, else insert a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query, and a standalone function call usually does not count as a query:

```
FOR booking IN select * from json_to_recordset(...
```

Also, you can't use BEGIN to start a transaction in plpgsql.  It is only used to start a block.  If you are using a procedure rather than a function, then you can COMMIT but then a new transaction starts immediately with no BEGIN token being used.

You are also missing a semicolon between the DELETE and the FOR, but from the error message that seems to be missing from only your post, and not from your actual code.